# Play Framework 2.2 TempoDB dependency

Tags: playframework, dependencies

I need to access a TempoDB database in my Play2 app, using the java api https://github.com/tempodb/tempodb-java.

I added the dependency in my build.sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.tempodb" % "tempodb-java" % "0.7.0"
)
```

I end up with the com.tempodb repository in play-2.2.1/repositories/cache/ , but that's it.
It doesn't appear when I do

```
play dependencies
```

I tried every

```
clean, reload, update
```

you can imagine, it always fails to compile whenever I add an

```
import com.tempodb.client.Client;
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok my bad, just found out, at first I had no build.sbt file so I created one but in the "project" folder instead of the root folder -_-

Moving it to the root app folder solved this.